# Java: how to write proper equals method for classes that really do not have any state?

Tags: java, networking, remoting, equals

Consider this interface:

```
public interface Listenable {
  void listen();
}
```

Consider this implementation:

```
public class Listener implements Listenable {
  public void listen() {
    System.out.println("I am listening");
  }
}
```

Now I am doing remoting via RMI and I am passing instances of such classes to server (maybe some black-magic proxies are spawn there, not sure).

The only solution I was able to invent so far, **and I have to say it's pretty idiotic**, is to add this code to Listener class:

```
public class Listener implements Listenable {
  private double id;
  private Random rand = new Random();
  public Listener() {
    this.id = rand.nextDouble();
  }
  public void listen() {
    System.out.println("I am listening");
  }
  public int hashCode() { ... } // calculate from id
  // same for equals - compare by id
}
```

This *usually* works, but we all know how evil this is :/ How should one deal with such a situation?

**UPDATE:**

Stanard equals did not work for me, because instances are over different VMs (I mentioned remoting), so it couldn't work. I will need some state variable after all, or suggest something good for comparing such classes on remote VMs. I am very sorry for confusion.

Comment: Why do you override `hashCode`?

Comment: If they don't have any meaningful state why are you trying to make an equals() method at all? This built-in can test for identity.

Comment: @Khackik if you override hashcode() you must override equals, thats part of the contract.

Comment: @ArtB, yes, but not backwards - you don't need to override `hashcode` to override `equals`. So it was a good question.

Comment: even if you use this way, don't use `this.id == other.id`.. it is a double, and thus the accuracy is not guaranteed... :\

Comment: sorry, just trying to understand better, where exactly will this equals()/hashcode() method will be used? What do you want to do by comparing 2 Listener object which are stateless?

Comment: @Mihir yes, but see CollinD's answer, that solved my problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make the listener an enum singleton:

```
public enum Listener implements Listenable {
  INSTANCE;

  public void listen() {
    System.out.println("I am listening");
  }
}
```

Then there will be only one instance of `Listener` and equality is guaranteed.

You may not want to expose the fact that you're using an `enum` for this or even that the listener is a singleton at all. What you can do is make the enum a private inner enum of some class with static methods (called `Listenables`, let's say) and just expose this implementation through a static method:

```
public static Listenable printingListenable() {
  return Listener.INSTANCE;
}
```

Comment: @Xorty: Yes. If you serialize `Listener.INSTANCE` on one machine and deserialize it on another, it will deserialize to the single instance of itself. Enums guarantee this for you.

Comment: @CollinD I am impressed. That work perfectly well! Do you have idea if that would work when interacting JRockit with HotSpot? I am afraid this won't ...

Comment: @Xorty: Should work fine. Enums are serialized by class name and constant name only, so when you serialize `com.foo.Listener.INSTANCE` it'll deserialize to the same thing on the other side (using the static method `Enum.valueOf`). It's not something VM specific.

Answer (score 4):

IMHO equality of objects is defined by the equality of their state. If the object does not hold any state (arguably it shouldn't be called an object, but that's a different story), all the instances of that object are logically equal. So don't bother and write:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  return obj instanceof Listener;
}

public int hashCode() {
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since listener is completely stateless, for many practical purposes different instances may be considered to be the same identity. In a nutshell, the class itself will determine identity. So how about this:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
   return obj!=null&&obj.getClass().equals(this.getClass());
 }

 public int hashCode() {
   return 0;
 }
}
```

I have a concern about `instanceof` as subclasses may not be considered the same object.

Answer (score 1):

If the objects dont have any state, then they all should be equal. Why the need to differentiate between them?